# Example of dependent random variables $X,Y$ such that there is no measurable $f$ with $Y=f(X)$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, independence

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space and $X,Y$ be real-valued random variables on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$.

If $X$ and $Y$ are dependent, can we always find a Borel measurable $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ with $Y=f(X)$?

This is actually equivalent to the claim that $Y$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable.

I guess the answer in general is "no", if we understand "dependent" as "not independent" and I guess $Y=f(X)$ for some Borel measurable $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a particular kind of dependence ... But what could dependence mean otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A,B,C$ be a partition of the sample space where each of the three sets has positive probability. Let $X=1$ on $A \cup B$ and $0$ on $C$. Let $Y=2$ on $A$, $3$ on $B$ and $1$ on $C$. Note that $P(X=1,Y=1) =0$ but $P(X=1) P(Y=1) >0$. Hence $X$ and $Y$ are not independent. However there is no $f$ such that $Y=f(X)$; this is because if such a function exists then $X=1$ implies $Y=f(1)$. But $Y$ take two distinct values on the set $X=1$.

Comment: Are there any common ways to express how random variables are dependent then?

Comment: @0xbadf00d In Probability Theory one talks about various 'types of dependence': uncorrelated random variables, Markov property, martingale property etc.

Comment: Hm, yes. I ask because I try to make a more rigorous sense of the claim that the covariance is measure the "linear dependence" of random variables. I'm not really sure what's exactly meant. Clearly, assuming $X,Y\in L^2$ and $\operatorname E[X]=\operatorname E[Y]=0$, the covariance of $X,Y$ is just the $L^2$-inner product. On the other hand, they are linearly dependent in the vector space $L^2$, if $Y=aX$ for some $a$ in which case $\operatorname{Cov}[X,Y]=a\operatorname{Var}[X]$.