# Connection between statistical and functional dependence of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables

For simplicity lets consider finite probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ and two random variables $\xi, \eta$ on it. I wonder is there any connection between statistical and functional dependence of random variables? For example, if I have $\xi = f\circ \eta$ for some $f$, does it imply that $\xi$ and $\eta$ statistically dependent and [vice versa](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vice_versa#Latin)? Or, if they are functionally independent, does it imply that they are statistically independent and vice versa?

Comment: @geetha290krm: Not quite. A constant RV is independent of itself (and of any other RV, in fact).

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3742186/532409

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is not constant, the functional dependence implies the dependence of $X$ and $f(X)$. Indeed, the following

$$\mathbb P (X \le a, f(X) \le b)=\mathbb P \big (X \in (-\infty,a], X \in f^{-1}(-\infty,b] \big )=\\\mathbb P \big  (X \in (-\infty,a]\big ) \times\mathbb P \big ( X \in f^{-1}(-\infty,b]\big )$$

cannot hold for all $a,b \in \mathbb R$ unless $X$ is a constant (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/512755/1231520)).

However, the dependence of $X$ and $Y$ does not imply that there is a measurable function $f$ such that $Y=f(X).$ Let $$(X,Y) \sim \mathcal N \left (0, \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & \rho \\
        \rho & 1 
      \end{bmatrix} \right ). $$

Then, $Y=\text{sgn}(\rho)X$ if and only if $\rho=\pm1$. For $0<|\rho|<1$, $X$ and $Y$ are dependent, but they are functionally independent, because there is no joint pdf for the pair $(X,f(X))$, whereas $(X,Y)$ has a joint pdf for $|\rho|<1$.